# Vagrant: Use already installed virtual machine with PuPHPet

Tags: php, vagrant, puphpet

I configured Vagrant via shell with my own bootstrap.sh. Now I am trying to create a virtual machine using PuPHPet.

How can I use the already installed virtual machine instead the one provided by PuPHPet?

Comment: Why is it important to keep the with vagrant created old system?

Comment: There is nothing particulary important. I just don't want to download another VM so I can save that download time. I'm asking this for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `Vagrantfile` that came from PuPHPet to have the same box definition as your initial `Vagrantfile`.

The setting that needs to be the same is `config.vm.box`

That should stop another box being downloaded, depending on which boxes you are using there is no guarantee that PuPHPet will work as expected though.